# WPF: StackPanel item auto-height question

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, layout, controls

I have a Stackpanel and want that the items automatically set their sizes regarding to their contents but the items should *not* automatically fill the height of the Stackpanel (But Stackpanel should have auto height according to largest item). I also tried WrapPanel which has the same problem.

I want the TextBox "test" be be vertically centered and automatically sized depending on its text.

```
                    <TextBox Name="test" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">test</TextBox>

                    <StackPanel  Name="ParameterList" Orientation="Vertical">

                            <TextBox Name="ParamComment" Foreground="Gray">no comment..</TextBox>


                            <TextBox Name="ParamComment2" Foreground="Gray">no comment..</TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>                                               
                </WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
    |stackpanelitem
test|stackpanelitem
    |stackpanelitem
```

then try this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="test"/>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBox Text="stackpanelitem"/>
    <!-- other items -->
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes I meant exactly that. Thanks for the answer. Why does StackPanel have Grid.Column="1" but the TextBox does not have Grid.Column="0"?  And what is the difference between "Auto" and "*"?

Comment: As you can see i defined two columns for the grid. Grid.Column is an attached property and just specifies in which column of the grid this control is placed. 0 is the default value, so it is not necessary. 
Auto means that the column will size automatically to the widest item, * means that it will take all the available space. If i had specified a third column with width *, then the two columns would each use half of the remaining space.